# Simple JS for loop to delete sheets in Google Sheets not looping

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a simple loop that will cycle through the tabs on google sheets and delete any tab (or sheet) after the specified sheet number (the 6th sheet in the example below). It deletes the correct sheet but does not continue in the loop. Instead, I receive an error that the specified sheetID no longer exists, and the loop stops. Any ideas on how to continue to the loop?

```
   function DeleteDateTabs() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var delsheet = ss.getSheets()[5];
  var totalsheetnum = ss.getNumSheets();

  Logger.log(delsheet.getSheetName());
  Logger.log(totalsheetnum);

      for  (i=6;i<totalsheetnum;i++) 
        { 
         ss.setActiveSheet(delsheet);
         ss.deleteActiveSheet();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you don't update delsheet in loop, that's why only first one, from line 4 is deleted. You should write something like

```
ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[5]);
```

in line 12 for it to work. Cleaned version for your case:

```
function DeleteDateTabs(limit) 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  while(ss.getNumSheets() > limit) 
    ss.deleteSheet(ss.getSheets()[limit-1]);
}
```

call it

```
DeleteDateTabs(6); // Remove all sheets after 6th.
```

for your case.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you for the quick reply. I never thought of calling the limit through the function. I'm still fairly new to JS (as you could probably tell), and was wondering if there were any good resources (blogs, youtube channels, etc) you could share or point me toward?

Comment: The most legendary book about JS is https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/README.md. It's not for noobs, but if you can make it you'll become a god of JS, at least for comparison with dummy

Answer (score 0):

```
function DeleteTabsAfterLastTabtIndex(lasttabindex) {
  var lasttabindex=lasttabindex||5;//default for debugging purposes
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts=ss.getSheets();  
  for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++) {
    if(i>lasttabindex) { 
      ss.deleteSheet(shts[i]);
    }
  }
}
```